# "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value", but the allocating function is not listed in the stack trace. How?

Tags: c++, valgrind

This is the part of some Valgrind log:

```
==1652== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==1652==    at 0x868DBFC: Dfm_db::io::Layer_cell_writer::end_cell() (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_db_io_layer.C:224)
==1652==    by 0x862C9FD: Dfm_db::Hdb_layer_writer::end_cell() (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/../Isrc/dfm/dfm_db_io_layer.h:916)
==1652==    by 0x861197F: Dfm_db::Hdb_writer::save_layer_geometries(Dfm_db::Hdb_layer_writer&, Drc_Hierarchical_database&, unsigned long, Drc_Hierarchical_geometry_type, bool, bool, bool, bool, Dfm_produced_layer_type) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_db_hdb_io.C:2362)
==1652==    by 0x8610755: Dfm_db::Hdb_writer::save_layer(Dfm_db::Database*, Drc_Hierarchical_database&, unsigned long, unsigned long, Dfm_db::Geometry_types, char const*, Dfm_db::Run_info&, Dfm_db::Layer_origin const&, char const*, bool, char const*, char const*, bool, Pdb_security*, bool, int, bool, bool, Dfm_db::must_be, Dfm_produced_layer_type) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_db_hdb_io.C:2102)
==1652==    by 0x8595B1E: Dfm_db::Database::save_layer(char const*, unsigned long, bool) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_database.C:2490)
==1652==    by 0x8594D39: Dfm_db::Database::save_layers(std::map, std::less, std::allocator > > >&) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_database.C:2317)
==1652==    by 0x85937B8: Dfm_db::Database::save_revision(bool) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_database.C:2082)
==1652==    by 0x4C6AE76: Cockpit_cli::save_revision(Dfm_db::must_be) (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/cockpit_db_rev_cli.C:520)
==1652==    by 0x4C15153: cockpit_save_revision (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/cockpit_db_hier_rev_cmds.C:529)
==1652==    by 0xD8BAC67: TclEvalObjvInternal (in /amy/ic_wg_server/CACHED_WG_SERVER/ic/comp/exports.v0-0_6-19-2015_engr-aoi/mgc_home/pkgs/icv_lib.aoi/lib64/libcalibre_utils.so)
==1652==    by 0xD8E3255: TclExecuteByteCode (in /amy/ic_wg_server/CACHED_WG_SERVER/ic/comp/exports.v0-0_6-19-2015_engr-aoi/mgc_home/pkgs/icv_lib.aoi/lib64/libcalibre_utils.so)
==1652==    by 0xD8E7280: TclCompEvalObj (in /amy/ic_wg_server/CACHED_WG_SERVER/ic/comp/exports.v0-0_6-19-2015_engr-aoi/mgc_home/pkgs/icv_lib.aoi/lib64/libcalibre_utils.so)
==1652==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==1652==    at 0x859F6DC: Dfm_db::Database::get_pl_index_level() const (/home/lvardany/tmp_IWA/ic/lv/aoi-asserts-valg/dfm/Isrc/dfm_database.C:4325)
```

The last line is a result of `--track-origins` option which shows exactly in which function an uninitialized value was created. The only magical part of this output for me is that the last function doesn't appear in the call stack. Also `--num-callers` option was given to `20`.

My question is how is it possible that the last function doesn't appear in a call stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easily. An example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

std::function<void()> callback;

void foo()
{
   int x;
   callback = [&]() { if (x > 5) std::cout << "hi"; };
}

int main()
{
   foo();
   callback();
}
```

Here, `foo` will not appear in the callstack of invoking `callback`.

You're thinking too linearly.